# Python: How do I assign a random number between two floats to a variable?

Tags: python

so I am stuck on how to make my program assign a random number between two floats to a variable. This is my code:

```
dmg = self.lvl/2
```

I want the damage to be a random selection between + 3 or -3 of the caharcters level divided by two. How would I do this?

```
dmg = random.randint(self.lvl/2+3, self.lvl/2-3)
```

I tried this but it did not work.

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3?

Comment: Python 3, I have imported the random module already in the code.

Comment: Are you expecting float output or an integer? You cannot give float values to `random.randint()` in any case, you'd have to round first.

Comment: Ah, yes, I just realized it has integer in it. The other answer gave me the correct code as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [random.uniform(a,b)](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.uniform).

```
 random.uniform(1.5, 1.9)
```

Gives `1.8733202628557872`

Hope this is what you want.